# Create Centos 7 minimal image for Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I`m installing Centos 7 minimal into my virtualbox with this settings

[image]

Then i create single "/" standard ext4 partition.

Partitions once installed are:

[image]

Once i upload as image and create instance, instance just don`t boot.

Here is the log from instance with my centos 7 minimal image:

```
    KBD: int09 handler: AL=0
PS2 keyboard initialized
All threads complete.
Scan for option roms
Searching bootorder for: HALT
drive 0x000fd900: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800
Returned 122880 bytes of ZoneHigh
e820 map has 7 items:
  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM
  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED
  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED
  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bfffe000 = 1 RAM
  4: 00000000bfffe000 - 00000000c0000000 = 2 RESERVED
  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED
  6: 0000000100000000 - 0000000130000000 = 1 RAM
Unable to lock ram - bridge not found
KBD: int09 handler: AL=0
enter handle_19:
  NULL
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
Booting from 0000:7c00
```

But is just stuck.

Here is log from Google Centos 7

```
KBD: int09 handler: AL=0
PS2 keyboard initialized
All threads complete.
Scan for option roms
Searching bootorder for: HALT
drive 0x000fd920: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800
Returned 122880 bytes of ZoneHigh
e820 map has 6 items:
  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM
  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED
  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED
  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bfffe000 = 1 RAM
  4: 00000000bfffe000 - 00000000c0000000 = 2 RESERVED
  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED
Unable to lock ram - bridge not found
KBD: int09 handler: AL=0
enter handle_19:
  NULL
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
Booting from 0000:7c00
 [H [J [1;1H [?25l [m [H [J [1;1H [20;7H [mUse the ^ and v keys to change the selection.                       

      Press 'e' to edit the selected item, or 'c' for a command prompt.    [4;80H  [7m [4;1H      CentOS Linux (3.10.0-327.4.4.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)                         [m [4;79H [m [m [5;1H      CentOS Linux (3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)                        [m [5;79H [m [m [6;1H      CentOS Linux, with Linux 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64                            [m [6;79H [m [m [7;1H      CentOS Linux, with Linux 0-rescue-c237d8614bd9258fe3d4b8048fbe651d        [m [7;79H [m [m [8;1H                                                                                [m [8;79H [m [m [9;1H                                                                                [m [9;79H [m [m [10;1H                                                                                [m [10;79H [m [m [11;1H                                                                                [m [11;79H [m [m [12;1H                                                                                [m [12;79H [m [m [13;1H                                                                                [m [13;79H [m [m [14;1H                                                                                [m [14;79H [m [m [15;1H                                                                                [m [15;79H [m [m [16;1H                                                                                [m [16;79H [m [m [17;1H                                                                                [m [17;79H [m [m [18;1H                                                                                [m [18;79H [m [18;80H  [4;79H [22;1H   The selected entry will be started automatically in 5s.                      [4;79H [22;1H   The selected entry will be started automatically in 4s.                      [4;79H [22;1H   The selected entry will be started automatically in 3s.                      [4;79H [22;1H   The selected entry will be started automatically in 2s.                      [4;79H [22;1H   The selected entry will be started automatically in 1s.                      [4;79H [22;1H   The selected entry will be started automatically in 0s.                      [4;79H [?25h [H [J [1;1H [H [J [1;1H[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
```

Comment: User was able to resolve similar issue on this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831028/booting-from-custom-image-in-gce-boot-hang-at-booting-from-00007c00).

Comment: @Faizan But i already have only one root partition with "boot" directory inside..

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato Did you follow the recommendations from this help center article? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your bootloader is no configured properly. The instructions form [the article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image#configure_bootloader):

> Configure the bootloader on the system so that it can boot on Compute
>   Engine.
>
> 1. Connect to the terminal on the system with the boot disk that you plan
>      to import.
> 2. Edit the GRUB config file. Usually this file is at
>      `/etc/default/grub`, but on some older distributions it might be located
>      in a non-standard directory.
> 3. Make the following changes to the GRUB config file:
>
>    - Remove any line that has `splashimage=`. Compute Engine does not support
>        splash screens on boot.
>    - Remove the rhgb and quiet kernel command line
>        arguments.
>    - Add `console=ttyS0,38400n8d` to the kernel command line
>        arguments so that the instance can function with the Interactive
>        Serial Console.
> 4. Regenerate the `grub.cfg` file. Use one of the following
>      commands depending on your distribution.
>
>    - Debian and Ubuntu: `sudo update-grub`
>    - RHEL, CentOS, SUSE, openSUSE: sudo
>        `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
> 5. Edit the `/etc/fstab` file and
>      remove references to all disks and partitions other than the boot disk
>      itself and partitions on that boot disk. Invalid entries in `/etc/fstab`
>      can cause your system startup process to halt.